# disable Next and Prev buttons in blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I've added the code of the Next and Prev. buttons in [my blog](https://www.bookskiki.com/) https://www.bookskiki.com/ but now I don't want to use them more, I tried to remove the code but when I removed it the content also removed. So tell please how to solve this.

the code

```js
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'/>

<div id='siki-out'/>

<div class='page-navigation'>
<div class='siki-next-prev' id='siki_prev'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.locale.languageDirection == &quot;rtl&quot;'>
<a><span>Back</span><span class='siki-prev'/></a>
<b:else/>
<a><span>Back</span><span class='siki-next'/></a>
</b:if>
</div>
<div class='siki-next-prev' id='siki_next'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.locale.languageDirection == &quot;rtl&quot;'>
<a><span>Read More</span><span class='siki-next'/></a>
<b:else/>
<a><span>Read More</span><span class='siki-prev'/></a>
</b:if>
</div>
<div id='siki-page-number'/>
</div>

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this to your CSS:

```
#siki_prev, #siki_next {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Or if you want the number to be gone too:

```
#siki_prev, #siki_next, #siki-page-number {
    display: none !important;
}
```